# Cookie domain not getting set

Tags: http, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, session-cookies

My response to the request(`localhost:8001`) has:

```
Set-Cookie:MY_SESSION=123456;Path=/;Domain=mysite.com;HttpOnly
```

As we can see the `domain` is `mysite.com`

But when i check chrome dev tool `resources tab --> cookies section` it says domain as localhost.

**Why it is not showing domain as `mysite.com` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it...its the domain matching rules:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3

the origin domain should be equal to or a parent domain of the domain mentioned in cookie domain field

more documentation:http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html